# AirConsole CSS different from App and from Google Chrome

Tags: css, airconsole

Hey guys!
A quick question. if anybody can help me...

I'm creating a game for AirConsole using HTML5/Javascript for my Controller.
I'm currently testing it and I found out that the CSS is not the same:

- When I play using the AirConsole App for the Controller
- When I use the Google Chrome browser on my phone.

Could any of you know why ? I can't access the code on the app so I can't know what is happening...

I would expect the AirConsole app to be have a wrapper of the Google Chrome webview and therefore, have the same displayed result.

Here is the view using Google Chrome on mobile (v62.0.3202.84):
[Google Chrome controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdt09.png)

And here is the result with the last version of the AirConsole app (v.2.0.6):
[AirConsole App Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKWt1.png)

Answer (score 2):

On Android AirConsole uses Crosswalk which uses Chromium Version 53. This is not the system webview which uses the latest chrome from Android.
We are going to change this at some point in the future to use the system webview, because Crosswalk development has been discontinued.

On iOS AirConsole uses the system WebView, which uses the internal Safari.

There is an option how you should be able to debug a controller in the App:
https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

This tool allows you to debug any webkit based webview in any app. It's a pure javascript solution.

Please note that WeinRe will only work over http and not over https. This means you will have to run your AirConsole game from a local host.

Disclaimer: I haven't recently used WeinRe, but I'm pretty sure it should still work today.

If it doesn't contact the AirConsole team at hello@n-dream.com and we can provide you with a debug APK build (Android only).

Comment: Hey Andrin!
Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I tried to remote debug but it only worked on Google Chrome.

I wanted to debug the AirConsole App since it is the one having issues with CSS. Google Chrome looks fine (if you look back at my screenshots provided).

Is there any way I can do it ? Debug AirConsole Controller app using remote debugging and my laptop ?